# I do not see how my question is a duplicate. How can I access my original questions?

Tags: discussion

I do not see how my question is a duplicate. Even worse I am redirected to another question.  This is clearly the shortest way to loose people potentially interested in the service this website is meant to suggest. Note it still has the most votes among the latest questions on the first page.

The question was

[Can I buy airfare using one passport (visa required) and then use another (no visa required) to enter the country? [duplicate]](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/56856/can-i-buy-airfare-using-one-passport-visa-required-and-then-use-another-no-vi)

and I asked it after reading all those earlier questions used to "prove" my question was a "duplicate".

Sorry but I do not want to discuss this in meta. I just want some good answers to a good question. Thanks.

EDIT: Thanks for the comments. I am getting re-directed here: [Travelling with two different passports](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3515/travelling-with-two-different-passports)

I had closed questions before with other communities,  even with more upvotes, but I always could access my own question. Anyway, my intention was that this follow-up question would be deleted after the issue has been resolved. I just did not want start a chat or another discussion on meta, as I'll probably never use this site again if you close good questions so easily.

Comment: Your original question is still available [here](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/56856/can-i-buy-airfare-using-one-passport-visa-required-and-then-use-another-no-vi). I can see how arguably these are not duplicates, but in my opinion if those answers give you everything you need to know. Short answer, probably yes -- if you're careful which passport you show at each stage.

Comment: You might not want to discuss it in meta, but that's where these discussions take place.  Or in [chat].  If it gets posted here it's just going to get closed :/

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "redirected".  Your question is the same as it was, it just has a link at the top to another question that some people thought was a duplicate.  If you have researched the linked question(s) and they don't answer your question, please edit your post to indicate the answers you have read and the specific questions you still have.  Then it can be reopened.

Comment: After some research, I found out that the redirection seems to happen to anonymous users as described [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125220/automatically-redirect-anonymous-user-from-unanswered-duplicate-question-to-corr). You should be able to see your question by adding ?noredirect=1 to the link. Maybe [this link](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/56856/can-i-buy-airfare-using-one-passport-visa-required-and-then-use-another-no-vi?noredirect=1) will work for you? This is a system wide feature, not exclusive to travel.SE.

Answer (score 5):

The question may not exactly overlap with yours, however it is very similar, and the top answers covers pretty much all your queries. That's why it's been marked as duplicate. If you feel your question isn't a duplicate, then best practice is to edit your question to emphasise (or perhaps even only) the issue that isn't duplicate, and then ask for it to be reopened. This can be somewhat problematic for low-rep users, as they lack the "reopen" button and the ability to make the request in chat.

Drat's comment above covers the redirection - it seems that it shouldn't be happening if you are logged in.

Comment: When a closed question is edited, it automatically goes to the reopen review queue.